# Function throwing segFault from seemingly no where?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

**Problem:**
Hi, I'm writing a chess game in c++. Currently I'm trying to implement a FEN parser into the game. But the function is throwing a seg fault at the end of the function.

**What I've tried:**
I've looked into the while loop but it does not go out of bounds and it exits the while loop seen by a print statement. I've tried changing the switch statements to if statements, that did not change anything, originally it was a void function I've now tried int and vector<vector< char> > and I've checked all i and j values so it doesn't go out of change in the vector.

**Code:**
Here is the function:

```
vector<vector<char> > passFEN(const char *FEN){
    vector<vector<char> > board;
    vector<char> row;
    char space = '_';


    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        row.push_back(space);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        board.push_back(row);
    }
    
    int j = 1, i = 0;
    char letter;
    char *fen; strcpy(fen, FEN);
    
    char *boardFen = strtok(fen, " ");
    printf("%s\n", boardFen);

    while(j <= 64){
        letter = boardFen[i];
        i++;
        int aFile = ((j-1) % 8);
        int aRank = ((j-1) / 8);
        printf("File = %i, Rank = %i, Count = %i, Letter = %c\n", aFile, aRank, j, letter);

        switch (letter)
            {
            case 'p' : board.at(aRank).at(aFile) = 'p'; break;
            case 'r' : board.at(aRank).at(aFile) = 'r'; break;
            case 'n' : board.at(aRank).at(aFile) = 'n'; break;
            case 'b' : board.at(aRank).at(aFile) = 'b'; break;
            case 'q' : board.at(aRank).at(aFile) = 'q'; break;
            case 'k' : board.at(aRank).at(aFile) = 'k'; break;
            case 'P' : board.at(aRank).at(aFile) = 'P'; break;
            case 'R' : board.at(aRank).at(aFile) = 'R'; break;
            case 'N' : board.at(aRank).at(aFile) = 'N'; break;
            case 'B' : board.at(aRank).at(aFile) = 'B'; break;
            case 'Q' : board.at(aRank).at(aFile) = 'Q'; break;
            case 'K' : board.at(aRank).at(aFile) = 'K'; break;
            case '/' : j--;
            case '1' : break;
            case '2' : j++; break;
            case '3' : j+=2; break;
            case '4' : j+=3; break;
            case '5' : j+=4; break;
            case '6' : j+=5; break;
            case '7' : j+=6; break;
            case '8' : j+=7; break;
            
            }
            j++;
            
     }
     printBoard(board);
     printf("exiting for loop\n");
     return b;
}
```

This is how I'm calling it

```
int main(){
    int wHeight = 1094;
    int wWidth = 1094;

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(wWidth, wHeight), "Chess");

    sf::Texture texture;
    if(!texture.loadFromFile("/Users/joelsmith/VSCode/chessC/chessBoard.png")){
        printf("Couldn't find file\n");
        return 0;
    }

    sf::Sprite sprite(texture);
    initializeBoard();
    b = passFEN(FEN);                             // Here
    printBoard(b);

// ...continues...
```

The terminal print out is

```
r n b q k b n r 
p p p p p p p p 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
P P P P P P P P 
R N B Q K B N R 
exiting for loop
zsh: segmentation fault
```

As you can see it's exiting the while loop *then* seg faulting. Also quick note the segFault is definitely coming from the function.

I must be doing something wrong somewhere. Any insight is appreciated thanks for reading.

Comment: you cannot know where the root cause is. The memory corruption can be in `initializeBoard` then everything can look ok, but the crash only happens in `passFEN`. Please create a [mcve] and post that

Comment: char *fen; strcpy(fen, FEN);

Comment: OT: We're not 1995 anymore. You are allowed to write `vector<vector<char>>` without having the compiler tableflip.

Comment: As @jls28 stated. your `strcpy` call scribbles over an uninitialized pointer. If you want to split a string by spaces look at `std::stringstream`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned,change the lines from

```
char *fen;
strcpy(fen, FEN);
```

to

```
char *fen = (char *)malloc(strlen(FEN) + 1);
strcpy(fen, FEN);
```

Also, looks like you were intending to return `board` instead of variable `b`.